# How to get rid of a gray filling in a ggplot graph legend (stacked bar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having troubles fixing a legend in my ggplot chart. I would like to get rid of the gray filling and have a square filled with the color assigned to a variable.

```
data = data.frame(Date = (seq(as.Date("2018-02-03"), as.Date("2019-05-05"), by = "days")),
                  var1 = runif(457),
                  var2 = runif(457)) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

ggplot(data = data, 
           aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("#A90046", "#D1EAFE"), name = "")
```

[image]

Comment: use `fill=variable` instead of `colour=variable`. You'll need to change to`scale_manual_fill` also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change aesthetic to `fill` and `scale_fill_manual` like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
data = data.frame(Date = (seq(as.Date("2018-02-03"), as.Date("2019-05-05"), by = "days")),
                  var1 = runif(457),
                  var2 = runif(457)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, 
       aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#A90046", "#D1EAFE"), name = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It seems obvious but it returns frequently that this mistake colour vs. fill is made!:-)

Comment: @TarJae, True! Practice makes perfect they say ;)